# Is there a way to find hanging or stuck threads in executor service?

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

Is there a way to find hanging or stuck threads in executor service thread pool?
or
Is there a way to find if all threads in executor service is hanging or stuck, so we could shutdown or restart executor service?

Stuck or hanging means, All Threads in executor service might be with Waiting state for long time without doing anything.  So no more threads to process other waiting tasks in executor service in such scenarios

Answer (score 1):

If you know how long the task will be running you can use `Future#get` to timeout the task so that it will not get stuck.

One example is supposed we want to run X number of task

```
/*
   spawn one thread only wait for each task to finish
*/
ExecutorService executorService=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
List<Runnable> runnables = ... ;
for(Runnable task : runnables)
{
  Future<?> future=executor.submit(task);
  try
  {
   future.get(2,TimeUnit.SECONDS); // exit task in 2 seconds
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: But this will block your thread where you call `Future#get`

Comment: @knittl the Future#get method will produce an exception when the task is still not done after 2 seconds.

Comment: correct, but before throwing the exception it will block the current thread for 2 seconds, waiting for the result to become available